# Slurm - job runs, gets data but gives TIMEOUT error

Tags: error-handling, centos, timeout, cluster-computing, slurm

So I'm running some code which takes about 2 hours to run on the cluster. I configured the batch file with

```
# Set maximum wallclock time limit for this job
#Time Format = days-hours:minutes:seconds
#SBATCH --time=0-02:15:00
```

Just to give some overhead if the job slows for whatever reason. I checked the directory that the generated files are stored in and the simulation completes successfully every time. Despite this, slurm keeps the job running until it hits the max time. The .out file keeps saying

`slurmstepd: *** JOB CANCELLED AT 2022-03-05T10:38:26 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***`

Any ideas why it doesn't show as complete instead?

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the code. But the idea that you are asking for is: your code did not finished in time. I'm not saying your simulation, I'm saying your code.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It finishes fine when ran locally

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this error is not related to `Slurm` rather about your application. Your application is somehow not sending the exit signal to the slurm.

You can use `sstat -j jobid` to see the status of the job, may be after 2 hours to see how the cpu consumption etc going and figure out what happens in your application (where it hangs after completion or so).